# Циклический сдвиг массива в PHP

Tags: php

Как можно сделать циклический сдвиг массива на 1 вправо, без циклов?

Comment: @IVsevolod, а чуть подробней про задачу? А то "*циклический, но без циклов*" - даже в голове с трудом укладывается.

Comment: @Deonis, имеется ввиду поместить последний элемент массива в начало массива, не используя циклов.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3);
array_unshift($array, array_pop($array));
var_dump($array); // 3, 1, 2
```

Не проверял, но должно работать. array_pop удаляет последний элемент из массива и возвращает его значение. array_unshift добавляет значение в начало массива.

Comment: работает :) спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста :)